# How to solve Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) Vulnerabilities in HTML/aspx site

Tags: html, asp.net, security, query-string, xss

I have something like this:

```
<td>
     <a href="pagina3.aspx?u=<%=request.querystring.get("u")%>&t=2&p=<%=Request.QueryString.Get("p")%>">
         <img src="image.png" />
     </a>
 </td>
```

But this way I have an XSS vulnerability detected. There's a proper way to use querystring and avoid the vulnerability or I have to change the way I pass the parameter?
I tried something like this:

```
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="pagina3.aspx">
            <input type="hidden" value="<%=request.querystring.get("u")%>" name="u" />
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="t" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<%=request.querystring.get("p")%>" name="p" />
<input type="image" value="submit" src="image.png" alt="submit Button" />
        </form>
     </td>
```

But it's not working, because all the page is in a master page that already have a form.
Any suggestion?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx#paght000004_step5

Comment: https://www.google..com/search?q=aspx+xss+querystring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you want to consider, the main one has to deal with XSS.

Yes, with your current implementation you are susceptible to XSS attacks.

**Contextual Encoding**

At a minimum what you should be doing is CONTEXTUALLY encoding the untrusted data (in this case the query string).

The important bit is making sure you are getting the right context for the encoding, per your example, you want to encode for an HtmlAttribute.

Depending on what version of the .Net framework you are using, you have two options:

.NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5 - use the [System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder(v=vs.110).aspx).

For older frameworks, download the [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library V4.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589)

Then your code would look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       value="<%= AntiXssEncoder.HtmlAttributeEncode(request.querystring.get("u")) %>" 
       name="u" />
```

For more Information on XSS read:

- [How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx#paght000004_step5)
- [Top 10 2013-A3-Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS))

**Hidden Fields**

In your example you are putting information into hidden fields.  Make sure you are not blindly trusting this data, this is easy for user to find and modify the values (it with developer tools in Chrome with no plugins).

References:

- [HPE Security: Hidden Field Vulnerability](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/java/hidden_field.html)
- [IDS14-J. Do not trust the contents of hidden form fields](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/IDS14-J.+Do+not+trust+the+contents+of+hidden+form+fields)

General Web App Security References

- [OWASP Top 10 2013](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)
- [Free eBook: OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/12/free-ebook-owasp-top-10-for-net.html)
- [PluralSight Courses](http://app.pluralsight.com/author/troy-hunt)

Comment: The example in the question with the hidden fields is not working, because all the page is in a master page that have a form. So I'm tryng with the first url solution. Is an old site with .NET Framework 2.0, so if I download that Library I can do something like: <a href="pagina3.aspx?u=<%=AntiXssEncoder.HtmlAttributeEncode(Request.querystring.get("u"))%>&t=2&p=<%=AntiXssEncoder.HtmlAttributeEncode(Request.QueryString.Get("p"))%>">

Comment: When doing the href values, while it is an HTML Attribute, you want to use the more specific URL encoder, UrlEncode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
 <td>
     <a href="pagina3.aspx?u=<%=Server.UrlEncode(Request.querystring.get("u"))%>&t=2&p=<%=Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString.Get("p"))%>">
         <img src="image.png" />
     </a>
 </td>
```

Comment: While this is a URL and you are doing contextual encoding, you want to use a library dedicated to AntiXss.  Server.HtmlEncode and Server.UrlEncode are designed to not break HTML which is not the same as designed to prevent XSS